# Airflow - copying Sqoop jars

Tags: airflow, sqoop

Going through the sqoop documentation [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) and found below

> Sqoop will copy the jars in $SQOOP_HOME/lib folder to job cache every
> time when start a Sqoop job. When launched by Oozie this is
> unnecessary since Oozie use its own Sqoop share lib which keeps Sqoop
> dependencies in the distributed cache. Oozie will do the localization
> on each worker node for the Sqoop dependencies only once during the
> first Sqoop job and reuse the jars on worker node for subsquencial
> jobs. Using option --skip-dist-cache in Sqoop command when launched by
> Oozie will skip the step which Sqoop copies its dependencies to job
> cache and save massive I/O.

Does airflow acts in the same way as oozie while importing? Have anyone tried this or do have any related info ?
TIA.